# Can you make sugar free whipped cocunut cream?

Tags: whipped-cream, sugar-free, coconut-milk

I typically avoid sugar but I love whipped cream . Is this a thing?
The question is pretty straightforward. Thanks so much!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

First, know that sugar is not a required ingredient when whipping cream. It will come together fine without adding anything to the cream.

As to coconut milk, it typically has a fat content around 25% (compared to about 35% for whipping cream.) While it's possible 25% is enough to work, [all the recipes](https://www.google.com/search?q=coconut+milk+whipped) I found skim off the water, resulting in an even higher fat content – likely 50%+ given the amount of water in a typical can of coconut milk.

So this is quite possible to do; personally I would try finding (or creating) a recipe that kept some or all of the liquid in, just in the interest of health and possibly making the resulting product a bit less heavy.

(Note this would definitely be something I would want to enjoy in moderation, given the extremely high amounts of saturated fat present in coconut milk.)

Comment: you can also buy cans of "coconut cream," which have a higher fat content to begin with. They will whip as-is.